# load a file with only its extension name

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I would like to load a file for only it's extension name in gensim.

A normal code would be this:

```
model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load("news.bin")
```

But I would like it to auto open any file with ".bin".

Example:

```
model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(***I would like to change this part to only load any .bin***)
```

.bin files:

It can be "news.bin", "file.bin" or "guess.bin". As long as it load only the extension. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to open all files that are in a folder that end in ".bin"?

Comment: Actually, I just want to open one file that ends in ".bin" but if possible to have both for open all and open one would be good. Will that trouble you? Or just open one and I will devise my own code for open all. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open **ALL** of them one by one, you can iterate over files in the target directory.

This is the code example for Python 3:

```
import os

directory_path = "/path/to/directory"

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith(".bin"): 
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(file_path)
        # Do whatever you want to do with model
```

If you only want to open **ANY ONE** of them, you can break out of the for loop after the first match:

```
import os

directory_path = "/path/to/directory"

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith(".bin"): 
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(file_path)
        # Do whatever you want to do with model
        # Break out of the for loop afterwards so it stops iterating
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library is perfect for this:

```
from glob import glob

for file_name in glob('*.bin'):
    model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(file_name)
```

This will loop over all files that match `*.bin` according to Unix style pathname pattern expansion.